# Silverlight and Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: silverlight, workflow-foundation

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     xxxxxxx.Workflow1_WebServiceSoapClient zer = new xxxxx.Workflow1_WebServiceSoapClient();
     zer.demanderSubmitReportCompleted += new EventHandler<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.demanderSubmitReportCompletedEventArgs>(service2);
     zer.demanderSubmitReportAsync("zzz", 20000);
 }

public void service2(object sender, xxxxx.demanderSubmitReportCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string a = e.Result;
}
```

I'm trying to call a [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://Windows%20Workflow%20Foundation) published as a web service from a Silverlight project. When I call it from a console application it works fine because I can add a web reference then I just make an instance of that webservice then I invoke the method I want. The problem is in the Silverlight project because I can just add a service reference so I find myself working with SOAP stuff that doesn't work at all, and here is the code error:

Here is the code: I change it a litle bit in English.

```
Error in exécution Microsoft JScript: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application  exception happened in the operation, résult not valide. Consult InnerException for more information.   in System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   in AEDSilverlightIntegrated.ServiceReference2.demanderSubmitReportCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   in AEDSilverlightIntegrated.SilverEntryAedHeaderNew.mmm_demanderSubmitReportCompleted(Object sender, demanderSubmitReportCompletedEventArgs e)
   in AEDSilverlightIntegrated.ServiceReference2.Workflow1_WebServiceSoapClient.OndemanderSubmitReportCompleted(Object state)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution and I want to share it with all of you. The solution is to build a web service that works as a bridge between Windows Workflow Foundation published as a web service and a Silverlight application. Not so genious, but this resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Make sure that the service exposes a [cross-domain policy file](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx) to allow Silverlight to make the cross-domain call.

This is only required if the service is on a different domain to the Silverlight host page.

Comment: i added the cross domain file but it doesnt work:


 <?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"> <cross-domain-policy> <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/> <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction" /> </cross-domain-policy>