# Silverlight and Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: silverlight, workflow-foundation

Can I make a Silverlight application communicate with a Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) application? If yes, how can I do that?

I tried to add a reference from my Silverlight application to a WF application and it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Silverlight and Windows Workflow Foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681653)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight and Windows Workflow Foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681653/silverlight-and-windows-workflow-foundation)

Answer (score 1):

If your application was a service application, then yes.

Silverlight won't host a workflow, but it could call a workflow service if the workflow you need to run is hosted within a service rather than an application.

It should be a matter of adding the service reference within the Silverlight application.

Comment: but if i publish my workflow as a webservice it doesnt work with a silverlight project